# Stereoscopic 3D for Android TV apps

Tags: 3d, sony, android-tv

I have a 3D TV which runs on Android TV, and I was wondering, if I were to create an app that displays 3D content, how would that app notify the TV to go into 3D mode? Is there some Android API to enable this?

When watching regular TV, there is a 3D menu that I can activate to switch the TV into side-by-side or over-under 3D mode. This 3D menu, however, is only available in a few Android apps, not all. For example, if I open the YouTube app, I can access the 3D menu, set it to "side-by-side", and watch a 3D video. I can do the same for the Videos app (though only in some cases) and the Amazon Video app. For most other apps, there is no 3D menu available. As an example, if I go to the Kodi app and enable the side-by-side UI in its settings, I see two copies of the Kodi interface; the TV does not switch into 3D mode.

I've searched online and found many forum posts about apps such as Plex and Kodi being unable to switch into 3D mode automatically. Some people suggest the workaround of activating 3D in the Video app, then switch over to Plex and Kodi where it should work (it didn't for me).

If it's relevant, my TV is a Sony Bravia. I access the 3D menu by pressing the "Action Menu" button on the remote. This button works in all apps, but the 3D option is only present in some of them, as you can see from [these images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1wRt.jpg). Also, it seems that the Video app has a settings option available from the action menu as well while Kodi doesn't; I'm not sure if that's related or not.

Comment: I don't think there is currently an available API for developing stereoscopic 3D apps for Android TV. We can just hope that google will release such an API in the future. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=5IOF-aFjqxw) is already 3 years old but I guess it is still relevant in your case, you can find it at 47:08.

Comment: We have a Mi-box connected to the TV. You start a 3d anaglyph video on your android telephone.
Then start screen mirroring to your TV.